# BufferReader unexpected output

Tags: java, file, bufferedreader

I have this simple method:

```
private String read(String filePath) throws IOException {
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(filePath);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
    String fileContent = "";
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(fileContent);

    while (bufferedReader.readLine() != null){
        System.out.println(bufferedReader.readLine());
        stringBuilder.append(bufferedReader.readLine());
    }
    return fileContent;
}
```

As you can see in line 8 I included print for debuging purposes 
I would like this method to return String from this txt file:

```
1a1
2b 2a
3c 3b 3a
4d 4cr 4bb4 4a
5e 5d 5c 5b 5ax
6f 6ea 6d 6ca 6bb 6a
7g 7f 7ea
```

for some reason output is like that:

```
2b 2a
5e 5d 5c 5b 5ax
null
```

Why it reads only second and fifth line? 
Where this null comes from?
String returned on the end seems empty.

I would like to understand what is happening here. Thx :)

Comment: Every call to readLine() reads a new line. You're reading 3 lines at each iteration of your loop.

Comment: And eventually you should close the FileReader upon method exit/return.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because you use every third line in the `while` loop's `null` check, print every third line counting from two, and append every third line counting from three, like this:

```
1  null check
2  print
3  append
4  null check
5  print
6  append
7  null check
8  print
9  append
... and so on
```

You should save the line you read in a `String` variable, and use it inside the loop, as follows:

```
String line;
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
    System.out.println(line);
    stringBuilder.append(line);
}
```

Now the loop header combines an assignment and a `null` check, and the variable assigned from `readLine` represents the last line read from the file.

Answer (score 2):

Each `readLine()` is reading an entirely new line, to analyze what's going on let's name each `readLine()` call.

```
while (bufferedReader.readLine() != null) {          // Read 1
    System.out.println(bufferedReader.readLine());   // Read 2
    stringBuilder.append(bufferedReader.readLine()); // Read 3
}
```

Now let's associate each `readLine()` with the line that it reads:

```
1a1                   // Read 1 while loop condition
2b 2a                 // Read 2 this is when we print it
3c 3b 3a              // Read 3 append to stringBuilder
4d 4cr 4bb4 4a        // Read 1 while loop condition
5e 5d 5c 5b 5ax       // Read 2 this is when we print it
6f 6ea 6d 6ca 6bb 6a  // Read 3 append to stringBuilder
7g 7f 7ea             // Read 1 while loop condition
                      // Read 2 this is when we print it (null)
                      // Read 3 append to stringBuilder
```

As you can see you're consuming a lot of lines, and you're only printing a few. Other's have pointed out great solutions to fix this already hence that's not in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem here: You call `bufferedReader.readLine()` each time, this actually reads a new line each time, so the first line is read in the `while` and discarded, the second line is `System.out.println`-ed, the third is written to file and so on. You Need to store the first line read and work wich this, like eg:

```
for (String line = bufferedReader.readline(); line != null; line = bufferedReader.readLine()) {
    System.out.println(line);
    stringBuilder.append(bufferedReader.readLine());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
1a1                   // Read 1 while (bufferedReader.readLine() != null) 
next 2a               // Read 2 System.out.println(bufferedReader.readLine()); --print
3c 3b 3a              // Read 3 stringBuilder.append(bufferedReader.readLine());-next
```